# IntegrityError "Exception: Field is not unique" for a OneToOneField with unique=True in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following in models.py

```
class Groups(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  calls_lim = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=2,unique=False)
  time_lim = models.IntegerField(max_length=4,blank=True,null=True,unique=False)
  ivr = models.OneToOneField(ivr,unique=False)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % (self.name)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=12)
  group = models.OneToOneField(Groups,unique=False)
  msg_rcv = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True,null=True)
  msg_snt = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True,null=True)
  last_call = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
  pin = models.IntegerField(max_length=6,blank=True,null=True)
  blacklist = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % (self.user)
```

When i try to do an insert for UserProfile, the field group throws this exception

```
Exception Value: column group_id is not unique
```

Snippet from views.py that causes Exception

```
group = Groups.objects.get(name=str(form.cleaned_data['group']))
UserProfile.objects.create(user=User,phone='12345',group=group)
```

Is this expected behavior? Is it wrong to use OneToOneField for group?

Thanks

Comment: "`create(user=User,...)`"? You're either hiding the `User` model by writing `User =  ...` or trying to convert the `User` model class to a `User` id, which makes no sense.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be setting `null=True` on everything. `msg_snt` and `msg_rcv` make no sense as `None` instead of `0`, for example.  Also, `max_length` does nothing on `IntegerField`. Finally, what's an `ivr`?

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively I would think Groups and Users have a many to many relationship (A user can be part of many groups and a group can consist of many users). If that is the case, use a ManyToManyField instead.

If in your case a User can be part of only one group, the group-user relationship is one to many and thus the UserProfile model needs to have a ForeignKey to group.

A OneToOnefield is used ONLY for a one to one relationship between two models.

Refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related

Comment: Thanks... i was confused with sql relations.